# Dúvida sobre ponteiros

Tags: c, array, ponteiro

Esse código cria matriz, inicializa e imprime, além de também somar, subtrair e multiplicar matrizes:

```
typedef struct{  
    int nl;  
    int nc;  
    int **elementos;  
}MATRIZ;  
void criar_matriz (int, int, MATRIZ *);  
void inicializar_matriz (MATRIZ *);  
void imprimir_matriz (MATRIZ *);  
void somar_matrizes (MATRIZ *, MATRIZ *,MATRIZ *);  
void subtrair_matrizes (MATRIZ *, MATRIZ *,MATRIZ *);  
void multiplicar_matrizes (MATRIZ *, MATRIZ *, MATRIZ *);  

void criar_matriz (int nl, int nc, MATRIZ *m) {  
    int i, j;       
    m->elementos = (int **) malloc (sizeof(int *)*nl);  
    if (!m->elementos) {  
        printf("Nao foi possivel reservar memoria para a matriz!\n");  
        exit(1);  
    }  
    for (i=0; i<nl; i++) {  
        m->elementos[i] = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int)*nc);  
        if (!(m->elementos[i])) {  
            printf("Nao foi possivel reservar memoria para a matriz!\n");  
            exit(2);  
        }  
    }  
    m->nl = nl;  
    m->nc = nc;  
    for (i=0; i<nl; i++)    
    for (j=0; j<nc; j++)  
    m->elementos[i][j] = 0;  
}  

void inicializar_matriz (MATRIZ *m) {  
    int i, j;  
    for (i=0; i<m->nl; i++)  
    for (j=0; j<m->nc; j++) {  
        printf ("\nEntre com matriz[%d][%d]=",i+1,j+1);  
        scanf ("%d",&(m->elementos[i][j]));  
    }  
}  
void imprimir_matriz (MATRIZ *m) {  
    int i, j;
    for (i=0;i<m->nl;i++) {  
        printf("\n|");
        for (j=0;j<m->nc;j++)  
            printf ("%5d", m->elementos[i][j]);  
        printf(" |");  
    }  
}  
void somar_matrizes (MATRIZ *m1, MATRIZ *m2, MATRIZ *m3) {  
    if (m1->nl==m2->nl && m1->nc==m2->nc) {  
        int i, j;  
        criar_matriz (m1->nl, m1->nc, m3);  
        for (i=0; i<m3->nl; i++)  
            for (j=0; j<m3->nc; j++)  
                m3->elementos[i][j] = m1->elementos[i][j] + m2->elementos[i][j];  
    } else {  
        printf ("A soma nao eh possivel!\n");  
    }  
}  
void subtrair_matrizes (MATRIZ *m1, MATRIZ *m2, MATRIZ *m3) {  
    if (m1->nl==m2->nl && m1->nc==m2->nc) {  
        int i, j;  
        criar_matriz (m1->nl, m1->nc, m3);  
        for (i=0; i<m3->nl; i++)  
            for (j=0; j<m3->nc; j++)  
                m3->elementos[i][j] = m1->elementos[i][j] - m2->elementos[i][j];  
    } else {  
        printf ("A soma nao eh possivel!\n");  
    }  
}  
void multiplicar_matrizes (MATRIZ *m1, MATRIZ *m2, MATRIZ *m3) {  
    if (m1->nc==m2->nl) {  
        int i, j, z;  
        criar_matriz (m1->nl, m2->nc, m3);  
        for (i=0; i<m3->nl; i++)  
            for (j=0; j<m3->nc; j++) {  
                m3->elementos[i][j] = 0;  
                for (z=0; z<m1->nc; z++)  
                    m3->elementos[i][j] += m1->elementos[i][z] * m2->elementos[z][j];  
            }  
    } else {  
        printf ("A multiplicacao nao eh possivel!\n");  
    }  
}
```

Mas eu não entendi por que ele põe índices em elementos sendo que ele não foi declarado assim. E pra que ele utiliza ponteiro pra ponteiro pra `int`; e qual seria a diferença caso fosse apenas um ponteiro pra `int`?

Comment: Se sabes inglês, dá uma olhada no [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/) especialmente a secção 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com matrizes (arrays bidimensionais) há umas subtilizas:

```
int a[10][10]
```

fica reservada uma área de memória contígua de 100 inteiros. E quando usas 
`a[2][2]`
acaba por ser transformado internamente em algo semelhante a

```
*(a+2+2*10)
```

ou seja um array unidimensional especial. Isso implica conhecer o "10" ou seja a dimensão interior da matriz.

Deste modo, quando defines os parâmetros da função que queres que funcione para matrizes de qualquer dimensão, temos problemas: **não tens um modo fácil 
de declarar uma matriz tamanho variável**  (há maneiras de dar a volta).

Ao declarares

```
int **a
```

ficas obrigado a uma mais complexa alocação de memória,
(que no caso que apresentaste não é contígua) e as ocorrências de `a[2][2]`
são interpretadas como:

```
 *(*(a+2)+2)
```

Esta declaração é independente da dimensão (e portanto boa para declaração de
parâmetros de funções envolvendo matrizes de tamanho variável).

Quando as matrizes são de grandes dimensões a **eficiência temporal e de
memória total ocupada, pode ser muito diferente**.

Answer (score 7):

É simples, em C não existem *arrays* de fato, é apenas um açúcar sintático, é só para facilitar a vida do programador. C só tem ponteiros. Então no fundo quando você escreve:

```
a[5]
```

na verdade o código disto é

```
*(a+5)
```

Então as formas de escrever *array* e ponteiros costumam ser intercambiáveis na maioria das situações.

Quando você tem matrizes é comum você ter um ponteiro que indica uma dimensão da matriz para outro ponteiro que é outra dimensão da matriz.

Um ponteiro para ponteiro de `int` significa que você tem um ponteiro que aponta para outro ponteiro e só este segundo ponteiro tem um ponteiro que aponta para um inteiro. Você tem duas indireções. Para acessar o dado real que você deseja você tem que descobrir primeiro onde está o endereço onde se encontra o endereço de onde está o valor. É como uma brincadeira de caça ao tesouro onde cada lugar da uma nova pista até chegar no tesouro.

Também não existem *strings* em C. Elas são ponteiros para `char`.

Então se você tiver um *array* de *strings*, no fundo tem um ponteiro (que simboliza o *array*) para um ponteiro (que simboliza a *string*). Então no fundo um *array* de *strings* no fundo é um *array* bidimensional.

```
char *texto = "texto"; //string
char **ponteiroParaTexto = &texto; //referência para a string
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Index.c).

C também não tem referências iguais a outras linguagens de mais alto nível. Ponteiros são usados para acessar uma referência.

Então toda vez que precisa acessar uma referência para um *array* ou uma *string*, ou mesmo para uma outra referência, terá ponteiro para ponteiro. Uma parâmetro se sabe que é alguma forma de ponteiro que será recebido por referência usará esta forma de indireção.

É possível ter vários níveis de indireção mas em geral duas é o limite prático para a imensa maioria dos problemas. Se precisar de mais, tem uma chance razoável do código estar confuso demais e deve ser refatorado.

---

Comment: ahhhhh, entendi. valeu o/

Comment: @poirot se entendeu e a resposta é satisfatória marque-a como a resposta da sua pergunta.