# Qual o significado do operador "&" (e comercial) na linguagem C?

Tags: c, ponteiro, operadores

Estou montando uma apostila em C e procuro uma forma clara de explicar este operador para o leitor, e acredito que essa dúvida vai ajudar bastante o pessoal que está começando.

Veja um exemplo:

#### Código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main ()
{
    int   idade;
    printf("Digite sua idade ");
    scanf("%d", &idade); 
    system ("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Pelo que entendi o `%d` e um [especificador de formato](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C/Entrada_e_sa%C3%ADda_simples#Especifica.C3.A7.C3.B5es_de_formato) que pode ser usado para leitura ou exibição de uma variável do tipo `inteiro`.

Qual o significado operador `&`?

Comment: Na linguagem C temos duas maneiras de passar parâmetros através valores e por referência & que usado esse operador.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual a diferença entre ponteiro e referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56470/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-ponteiro-e-refer%c3%aancia)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Nesse contexto é o operador "endereço de". Então o resultado dele sempre será o endereço de memória do objeto em questão (em geral o local onde uma variável está alocada na memória). Ou seja, ele cria um ponteiro.

Esta é a forma típica do C para passar um argumento para uma função. Em C essa passagem sempre tem que ser explícita, já que todas passagens se dão por valor (em geral as linguagens são assim, mas algumas escondem isso e parece que estão passando por referência). Neste caso está passando o valor que é o endereço de memória, que será interpretado em algum lugar pegando o valor que está sendo apontado por este endereço, criando assim uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

No caso específico o `scanf()` espera justamente um endereço onde ele deve armazenar o que for digitado pelo usuário. Por isso está sendo passado com este operador.

Para esta função não interessa o valor guardado na variável e sim onde ela está.

Um erro comum é o programador inexperiente usar este operador em uma variável que é um ponteiro. Aí não precisa, porque a variável já contém o endereço do objeto apontado (a não ser que queira um ponteiro para ponteiro, mas isto não é comum).

O código `scanf("%d", &idade);` pode ser lido como: "leia dados em formato de valor decimal inteiro e armazene **no endereço de idade**".

O operador oposto é o `*` que é pegar o valor apontado pelo endereço.

Não confundir o [operador `&` usado em outro contexto que faz um cálculo de *and* nos bits](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91049/101), é o mesmo símbolo, mas outro operador.

Em C++ também é usado como outro operador ou declarador para indicar referência (que só existe concretamente nesta linguagem e não em C) que é parecido, mas um pouco diferente de ponteiro.

- [Qual a diferença entre ponteiro e referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101)
- [Como funcionam os ponteiros do C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106227/101)
- [Dúvida sobre ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53993/101)
- [Arrays são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101)
- [Função com passagem por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45646/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado ! você acha de devo deixar o titulo assim ? não consegui pensar em nenhum outro, acho que assim está ok.

Comment: Acho que está bom, se eu pensar em algo melhor, eu edito.

Answer (score 7):

O operador & extrai o endereço de memória de uma determinada variável, que pode ser usado para uma grande variedade de coisas.

## **Exemplos:**

Suponhamos que você queira criar uma função que adicione um inteiro x a uma variável inteiro y. O que muitos leigos e iniciantes fariam seria:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void adicionar( int x, int y){
    y += x;
}

int main(){
    int a = 5, b = 2;
    printf("Valor inicial de b: %i\n", b);
    adicionar(a, b);
    printf("Valor final de b: %i", b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Valor inicial de b: 2
Valor final de b: 2
```

Ué, mas não pedimos à função `adicionar` que modifica-se o valor da variável b?
Infelizmente não é assim que as coisas funcionam: Quando passamos b à função `adicionar`, passamos uma *cópia* de b para a função. Por que isso acontece? Porque a função pediu o *valor* contido em b, e não seu *endereço na memória*. Dessa maneira, é impossível modificar a variável b original.

Podemos pensar nessa situação da seguinte maneira: Na função `adicionar`:

```
void adicionar( int x, int y){
    int x = x;
    int y = y;
}
```

Ou seja, quando uma função requisita um `valor` de uma variável, é como se internamente ele recriasse as variáveis que passamos, só que em um escopo próprio. Dessa maneira, as variáveis que passamos como argumento são desprezadas, e as variáveis do escopo da função são utilizadas.

Para resolver esse problema infortuno, uma alternativa seria modificar a função adicionar da seguinte maneira:

```
void adicionar( int x, int *y){
    *y += x;
}
```

Aqui, pedimos um **ponteiro** para inteiro y. Isso quer basicamente dizer que estamos requisitando um endereço de memória de uma variável, ou seja, um local na memória que modificaremos dentro da função. O trecho de código `*y += x` basicamente faz a *desreferência* do ponteiro y, e adiciona a essa desreferência o valor x. Para facilitar a compreensão, poderíamos escrever o seguinte pseudo-código de função:

```
void adicionar( cópia de inteiro x, ponteiro para inteiro y){
    Desreferencie, ou seja, obtenha o endereço de memória para o qual y aponta.
    Em seguida, some a cópia do valor de x ao ponteiro recentemente desreferenciado.
}
```

Nesse caso, podemos fazer o seguinte em nossa função `main()`:

```
int main(){
    int a = 5, b = 2;
    printf("Valor inicial de b: %i\n", b);
    adicionar( a, &b);
    printf("Valor final de b: %i\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Valor inicial de b: 2
Valor final de b: 7
```

Mas o que é esse tal `&` que inserimos antes de b ao chamar a função adicionar? O que ele faz? Muito simples: Ele passa um ponteiro para um endereço de memória! É como se estivéssemos implicitamente iniciando o parâmetro y do protótipo de nossa função com o endereço de b! Desta maneira, quando desreferenciamos y dentro da função `adicionar`, estamos fazendo com que o endereço de b, para o qual y está apontando, tenha seu valor modificado!

Portanto, conclui-se que `&` é um operador que nos permite acessar e modificar um endereço de memória de uma variável.

Poderíamos também modificar o conteúdo de b sem o uso de funções utilizando a indireção de ponteiros acoplada ao uso do operador `&`. Por exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a = 5, b = 2, *c = NULL;
    c = &b; //c agora aponta para o endereço de b, obtido com o operador &.
    *c += a; //O valor contido no endereço para qual c aponta (b) é igual a ele mesmo mais a.
    printf("O valor de b é: %i", b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
O valor de b é: 7
```

Um outro uso de `&`, menos conhecido por iniciantes, é para a realização da operação lógica AND. Por exemplo:

```
if((24 & 50) > 30){
    puts("(24 & 50) é maior que 30.");
}
else{
    puts("(24 & 50) é igual ou menor que 30.");
}
```

Sabendo-se que `&` representa, nesse caso, a operação lógica AND, obtém-se:

```
0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0
0    0    1    1    0    0    1    0
____________________________________
0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
```

Como o resultado obtido é 16 na base decimal, o output dessa estrutura condicional é:

```
(24 & 50) é igual ou menor que 30.
```