# Como me livro desses warnings

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro

Estou fazendo um programa que caça uma palavra dentre de uma matriz. Para isso fiz 8 funções que varrem em todas as regiões, como preciso devolver na saída as coordenadas da primeira e da última letra.

Por exemplo, preciso encontrar a palavra "casa" na matriz, o programa devolve as coordenadas da letra 'c' e da letra 'a' (última letra), como as entradas eu tenho e preciso de dois valores na saída.

Usei ponteiros como parâmetros, só que está dando muito warning. Ainda falta para terminar o código completo.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int Norte (char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int *pc, int *pl) {
    int i, j, n, k;
    j = *pc; k = 0;
    n = strlen(palavra);
    for (i = *pl; i < i+n; i++) {
            if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) return -1;
            else k++;
    }
    *pl = i;
}

int Sul (char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int *pc, int *pl) {
    int i, j, n, k;
    j = *pc; k = 0;
    n = strlen(palavra);

    for (i = *pl; i < i+n; i++) {
            if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) return -1;
            else k++;
    }
    *pl = i;
}

int Leste (char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int *pc, int *pl) {
    int i, j, n, k;
    i = *pl; k = 0;
    n = strlen(palavra);

    for (j = *pc; j < j+n; j++) {
            if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) return -1;
            else k++;
    }
    *pc = j;
}

int Oeste (char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int *pc, int *pl) {
    int i, j, n, k;
    i = *pl; k = 0;
    n = strlen(palavra);

    for (j = *pc; j < j+n; j--) {
            if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) return -1;
            else k++;
    }
    *pc = j;
}

int Nordeste (char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int *pc, int *pl) {
     int i, j, n, k;
     k = 0;
     n = strlen(palavra);

     for (i = *pl, j = *pc; i < i+n; j++, i--) {
            if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) return -1;
            else k++;
     }
     *pl = i; *pc = j;
}

int Noroeste (char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int *pc, int *pl) {
     int i, j, n, k;
     k = 0;
     n = strlen(palavra);

     for (i = *pl, j = *pc; i < i+n; j--, i--) {
            if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) return -1;
            else k++;
     }
     *pl = i; *pc = j;
}

int Sudeste (char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int *pc, int *pl) {
     int i, j, n, k;
     k = 0;
     n = strlen(palavra);

     for (i = *pl, j = *pc; i < i+n; j--, i++) {
             if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) return -1;
             else k++;
     }
     *pl = i; *pc = j;
}

int Sudoeste (char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int *pc, int *pl) {
     int i, j, n, k;
     k = 0;
     n = strlen(palavra);

     for (i = *pl, j = *pc; i < i+n; j++, i++) {
             if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) return -1;
             else k++;
     }
     *pl = i; *pc = j;
}

int main () {

    char cacapalavra [100][100];
    char palavra [100];
    int i, j, k, n, *pc, *pl, aux;
    k = 0;

    scanf ("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
          for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                scanf ("%c", &cacapalavra[i][j]);

    scanf ("%s", palavra);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (palavra[k] == cacapalavra[i][j]) {
                *pc = j; *pl = i;
                aux = Norte(cacapalavra, palavra, &pc, &pl);
                aux = Sul(cacapalavra, palavra, &pc, &pl);
                aux = Leste(cacapalavra, palavra, &pc, &pl);
                aux = Oeste(cacapalavra, palavra, &pc, &pl);
                aux = Nordeste(cacapalavra, palavra, &pc, &pl);
                aux = Noroeste(cacapalavra, palavra, &pc, &pl);
                aux = Sudeste(cacapalavra, palavra, &pc, &pl);
                aux = Sudoeste(cacapalavra, palavra, &pc, &pl);
                }
          }
    }
}
```

Warnings:

> ```
> ||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c||In function 'main':|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|120|warning: passing argument 3 of 'Norte' from incompatible pointer type|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|5|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|120|warning: passing argument 4 of 'Norte' from incompatible pointer type|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|5|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|121|warning: passing argument 3 of 'Sul' from incompatible pointer type|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|17|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|121|warning: passing argument 4 of 'Sul' from incompatible pointer type|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|17|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|122|warning: passing argument 3 of 'Leste' from incompatible pointer type|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|29|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|122|warning: passing argument 4 of 'Leste' from incompatible pointer type|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|29|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|123|warning: passing argument 3 of 'Oeste' from incompatible pointer type|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|41|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|123|warning: passing argument 4 of 'Oeste' from incompatible pointer type|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|41|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|124|warning: passing argument 3 of 'Nordeste' from incompatible pointer type|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|53|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|124|warning: passing argument 4 of 'Nordeste' from incompatible pointer type|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|53|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|125|warning: passing argument 3 of 'Noroeste' from incompatible pointer type|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|65|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|125|warning: passing argument 4 of 'Noroeste' from incompatible pointer type|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|65|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|126|warning: passing argument 3 of 'Sudeste' from incompatible pointer type|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|77|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|126|warning: passing argument 4 of 'Sudeste' from incompatible pointer type|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|77|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|127|warning: passing argument 3 of 'Sudoeste' from incompatible pointer type|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|89|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|127|warning: passing argument 4 of 'Sudoeste' from incompatible pointer type|
> C:\Users\mdesousa\Documents\cacapalavra.c|89|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'|
> ||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 16 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
> ```

Comment: Quais *warnings*? Onde?

Comment: No final "warning: passing argument 3 of 'Norte' from incompatible pointer type|", sei que é a passagem do ponteiro, mas não sei como tirar. Tô rodando no codeblocks

Comment: A edição tinha escondido eles. Tem muito erro nesse código, vai ser dicífil achar todos. E o pior, que mesmo que compile, eu não vou confiar nele nunca sem fazer uma avaliação profunda. Tem coisa que eu nem sei como consertar, teria que entender o que o código todo faz para resolver. Um exemplo é que as função não retornam nada em determinadas situações. Tem que retornar, mas o que?

Comment: Pelo que entendi o warnings são da passagem do ponteiro para função, todas as função são muito parecidas.

Comment: Esse é apenas um problema, esse você resolve passando as variáveis sem `&`. Falo disso em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101 Parte do problema é o código estar desorganizado, algumas coisas não são fáceis de enxergar.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Comment: O erro está na hora de passar os parâmetros, por exemplo para o "Norte". Essa variável já é um ponteiro para "int", logo, você não pode colocar o "&" em pc na frente, senão você estará interpretando o ponteiro como um ponteiro do ponteiro.

Comment: Experimente declarar assim: int **pc, se deseja ponteiro do ponteiro

Answer (score 4):

Arrumei as [variáveis que estavam sendo enviadas com `&` e já são ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101). Coloquei retornos na funções (chutei um valor só para acabar com *warning*), fiz uso da variável `aux` e atribuí valores para as variáveis `pc` e `pl`. Duvido que faça o que deve, mas resolvi o problema descrito na pergunta, se a pergunta tiver mais detalhes eu melhoro. O código pode ser bastante melhorado.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int Norte(char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int *pc, int *pl) {
    int i, j, n, k;
    j = *pc; k = 0;
    n = strlen(palavra);
    for (i = *pl; i < i + n; i++) {
        if (cacapalavra[i][j] != palavra[k]) return -1;
        else k++;
    }
    *pl = i;
    return 0;
}

int Sul(char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int *pc, int *pl) {
    int i, j, n, k;
    j = *pc; k = 0;
    n = strlen(palavra);
    for (i = *pl; i < i + n; i++) {
        if (cacapalavra[i][j] != palavra[k]) return -1;
        else k++;
    }
    *pl = i;
    return 0;
}

int Leste(char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int *pc, int *pl) {
    int i, j, n, k;
    i = *pl; k = 0;
    n = strlen(palavra);
    for (j = *pc; j < j + n; j++) {
        if (cacapalavra[i][j] != palavra[k]) return -1;
        else k++;
    }
    *pc = j;
    return 0;
}

int Oeste(char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int *pc, int *pl) {
    int i, j, n, k;
    i = *pl; k = 0;
    n = strlen(palavra);
    for (j = *pc; j < j + n; j--) {
        if (cacapalavra[i][j] != palavra[k]) return -1;
        else k++;
    }
    *pc = j;
    return 0;
}

int Nordeste(char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int *pc, int *pl) {
    int i, j, n, k;
    k = 0;
    n = strlen(palavra);
    for (i = *pl, j = *pc; i < i + n; j++, i--) {
        if (cacapalavra[i][j] != palavra[k]) return -1;
        else k++;
     }
     *pl = i; *pc = j;
     return 0;
}

int Noroeste(char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int *pc, int *pl) {
     int i, j, n, k;
     k = 0;
     n = strlen(palavra);
     for (i = *pl, j = *pc; i < i + n; j--, i--) {
        if (cacapalavra[i][j] != palavra[k]) return -1;
        else k++;
     }
     *pl = i; *pc = j;
     return 0;
}

int Sudeste(char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int *pc, int *pl) {
    int i, j, n, k;
    k = 0;
    n = strlen(palavra);
    for (i = *pl, j = *pc; i < i + n; j--, i++) {
        if (cacapalavra[i][j] != palavra[k]) return -1;
        else k++;
    }
    *pl = i; *pc = j;
    return 0;
}

int Sudoeste(char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int *pc, int *pl) {
    int i, j, n, k;
    k = 0;
    n = strlen(palavra);
    for (i = *pl, j = *pc; i < i + n; j++, i++) {
        if (cacapalavra[i][j] != palavra[k]) return -1;
        else k++;
    }
    *pl = i; *pc = j;
    return 0;
}

int main () {
    char cacapalavra [100][100];
    char palavra [100];
    int k = 0, n, *pc = 0, *pl = 0, aux;
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) scanf("%c", &cacapalavra[i][j]);
    scanf ("%s", palavra);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (palavra[k] == cacapalavra[i][j]) {
                *pc = j; *pl = i;
                aux = Norte(cacapalavra, palavra, pc, pl);
                aux = Sul(cacapalavra, palavra, pc, pl);
                aux = Leste(cacapalavra, palavra, pc, pl);
                aux = Oeste(cacapalavra, palavra, pc, pl);
                aux = Nordeste(cacapalavra, palavra, pc, pl);
                aux = Noroeste(cacapalavra, palavra, pc, pl);
                aux = Sudeste(cacapalavra, palavra, pc, pl);
                aux = Sudoeste(cacapalavra, palavra, pc, pl);
                printf("%d", aux); //só para eliminar o warning que não foi usada.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fEGiNZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bnizyapw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Crosswords.c).

Comment: Gostei do "Veja compilando no ideone", haha.

Comment: Gostaria de saber o que tem de errado no código para receber negativo. Eu sei que ele não está perfeito, eu disse isso. Mas eu resolvi os problemas colocados na pergunta. Só o negativo não vai ajudar ninguém saber o que tem de errado.

Comment: O problema é a atribuição do ponteiro. No início declara-se que `int *pc = 0`, ou seja, ele é `NULL` e logo em seguida faz `*pc = j`, ou seja, está de-referenciando um ponteiro que é NULL. Deve estar cheio de erro o programa, mas esse é muito óbvio para deixar passar. A solução correta seria eliminar o ponteiro e passar o endereço da variável para a função;

Comment: Como eu disse, resolvi só o problema do *warning* conforme ele pediu, alertei que o código ainda está cheio de erros, não é só esse. A intenção não é fazer tudo para ele, mas resolver o que ele pediu. Tanto que nem coloquei que o código está funcionando, só que está compilando. Se ele quiser outras ajudas ele pode abrir outras perguntas. O foco desta é o *warning*. Eu não introduzi o erro, eu apenas não corrigi.

Comment: O int *pc = 0 entendi. Na segunda parte não entendi, preciso que o endereço na posição da matriz seja atualiza, por isso coloquei *pc = j. O que me tá mais me deixando em duvida são estes warning, quanto aos outros erros não tem problema, acredito que possa arruma-los sem maiores problemas.