# Exercício com pares e ímpares em C

Tags: c

Enunciado - Faça um algoritmo que leia um conjunto de números (X) e indique a quantidade de números pares (QPares) e a quantidade de números ímpares (QImpares) lidos.

Nota: a introdução de valores termina quando o utilizador insere 0.

```
      #include <stdio.h>
      main(){
      int num,res,qpar=0,qimp=0;
      while(num!=0){
      printf("Introduza");
      scanf("%d",&num);
        res=num%2;
       if(res==0){
        qpar++;
    } else {
        qimp++;
    }
   }
  printf("Pares -> %d\n",&qpar);
  printf("Impares -> %d\n",&qimp);
}
```

Não sei o que estou a fazer de errado nisto, ele compila bem mas o problema é que não me dá os valores certos de números pares e ímpares. De resto ele também está a fazer o ciclo corretamente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem erros, o `&` não é usado para printar.
Mais uma condicional para validar antes o zero de forma que ele não entre como par.

*Código*

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main(){
      int num,qpar=0,qimp=0;
      float res;
      do{
          printf("Introduza");
          scanf("%d",&num);
          if(num!=0){ //Condicional para que  o 0 não conte como par    
              res=num%2;        

              if(res==0){
                  qpar++;
              } else {
                  qimp++;
              }
          }
      }while((num!=0));
      printf("Pares -> %d\n", qpar); //Retirado o &
      printf("Impares -> %d\n", qimp); //Retirado o &
  }
```

Comment: Retirei o & do meu código e deixou de fazer o ciclo... mas o seu código está a funcionar na perfeição.

Answer (score 3):

O seu erro está aqui:

```
    printf("Pares -> %d\n", &qpar);
    printf("Impares -> %d\n", &qimp);
```

Tire esses `&`. Você não quer mostrar os endereços das variáveis, e sim os valores. O que você quer é isso:

```
    printf("Pares -> %d\n", qpar);
    printf("Impares -> %d\n", qimp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Organizando o código ajuda identificar o problema. No caso específico é que está mandando imprimir um ponteiro para inteiro no lugar de um inteiro. Se fosse compilado como deve, nem compilaria. e já seria apresentado um erro.

O `scanf()` precisa passar um ponteiro, por isso usa o operador `&`([endereço de](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101)) porque precisa dizer onde será armazenado o valor lido do teclado. no `printf()` não deve fazer isso, é o próprio valor que deseja imprimir e não o endereço onde ele está.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num = 1, qpar = 0, qimp = 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        printf("Introduza\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            qpar++;
        } else {
            qimp++;
        }
    }
    printf("Pares -> %d\n", qpar);
    printf("Impares -> %d\n", qimp);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9h4c8O). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ogpegojk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/EvenOdd2.c).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, retirei os & como disse mas dessa maneira o programa deixou de fazer o ciclo não sei porque razão... Apresenta-me pares e impares como 0 logo depois de executar...

Comment: @NopeNope não é para acontecer isso, viu o meu executando normal? Deve ter mudado algo mais que não deveria.

Comment: Está com o mesmo problema do meu

Comment: Não está, o meu está perfeito, você entrou no *link*? ele mostra o resultado perfeitamente. Vou por de novo aqui: http://ideone.com/ZsnkYa

Comment: Sim mas n sei porque, quando o passo para o dev c ele não me deixa introduzir valores.

Comment: Esse IDE (acho que está falando do DEVC++) é muito ruim. Mas pode ser que tenha outro problema que introduziu no código. Copie esse que está aqui cole lá e veja se funciona. Volto repetir se não mater o código organizado é fácil se perder.

Comment: @bigown o problema não é a IDE, fiz pelo DevC++, o problema é a ordem lógica, mais precisamente o while.

Comment: @FelipePaetzold pode ser, mas o meu está funcionando.

Comment: @bigown funciona, mas dessa maneira está contando errado os pares e ímpares, frisando que 0 é uma tecla para sair do looping e não um par.

Comment: @FelipePaetzold pode ser, mas isso não está especificado na pergunta. O certo seria até fechar a pergunta por não estar claro. Você "adivinhou" o que ele queria. Poderia muito bem querer contar e o algoritmo atual dele indica isso.

Comment: @bigown "a introdução de valores termina quando o utilizador insere 0.". Foi especificado.

Comment: Mas não diz se ele deve ser incluso ou não na contagem e o código dele incluía. Ou seja, você acertou porque acrescentou por sorte um requisito que não tinha na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ex_3()
{
    int n,c=1;
    do
    {
        printf("DIGITE UM NUMERO INTEIRO: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n<=0)
        {
            c=0;
        }
        else if(n%2==0)
        {
            printf("O NUMERO %d E PAR\n", n);
        }
        else
            printf("O NUMERO %d E IMPAR\n", n);
    }
    while(c!=0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consigo identificar um novo erro no seu código, você não inicia a variável `num` antes de começar a checar o `while`. Isso pode ser um problema pois a região de memória referenciada pela variável pode conter 0, se for o caso, o seu `while` será ignorado.

**Vejo duas soluções:**

> - Trocar sua estrutura de repetição por um do while.
> - Simplesmente realizar um scanf de num antes de entrar no while.
>   O erro do printf já foi identificado, mas vale lembrar que quando você coloca o & na frente de uma variável você está pedindo o endereço de memória dela.

Não sei se você fez isso pra postar aqui, mas é sempre bom separar algumas linhas com espaços em branco, onde faz sentido. Separar o código todo pode deixar ele tão bagunçado quanto não separar

Boa sorte, keep coding.