# Por que pode passar um vetor de char para o scanf() como endereço ou a variável direto?

Tags: c, array, string, ponteiro, matriz

Se o nome do vetor ou matriz já é o endereço do primeiro elemento, por que no `scanf()`, usando os tipos primitivos (`int`, `char`, `float`, `double`) eu preciso passar o endereço, sendo que quando queremos ler uma `string("%s")` não precisa? E outra, por que quando a gente vai ler strings com o `scanf()`, mesmo usando o `&`, ele compila?

Comment: Patrick, a resposta do @Maniero está correta. Existem erros conceituais na minha resposta. Creio que seja mais adequado marcar a resposta dele como a certa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Existem erros conceituais na minha resposta. Só percebi após a [resposta do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/251928/64969). Mas não pude remover, ela já estava marcada como aceita.
>
> Então, enquanto não corrijo/removo esta resposta, refiram-se a [resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/251928/64969) para algo correto e mais preciso.

> se o nome do vetor ou matriz já é o endereço do primeiro elemento, por que no scanf, usando os tipos primitivos (int, char, float, double) eu preciso passar o endereço

Você está falando em `int abc[5]; scanf("%d", &abc[0]);`, certo?

Quando você faz `abc`, você está pegando o endereço de memória do primeiro elemento. Ao fazer `[n]`, você "salta" `n` casas e pega o valor contido na casa `n`.

Por exemplo:

```
 (intA) (intB) (intC) (intD) (intE)
 [----] [----] [----] [----] [----]
 0      1      2      3      4
```

Se você por `abc[0]`, você vai pegar o valor contido em `intA`.

Ao por `&abc[0]`, você pega o endereço que aponta para `intA`.

> sendo que quando queremos ler uma string (`"%s"`) não precisa?

A leitura de string do `scanf` vai pegar o que foi digitado e colocar no endereço de memória passado. Quando se usa strings com alocação estática, temos um vetor de caracter. O uso é assim:

```
char palavra[100];
scanf("%s", palavra);
```

Aqui, cada caracter lido vai ser posto na posição correspondente. Por exemplo, a palavra `"abc"`:

```
(chrA) (chrB) (chrC) (chrD) (chrE)
 [----] [----] [----] [----] [----]
 0      1      2      3      4
[a]    [b]    [c]    [\0]
```

O caracter `a` ficou na posição 0 do vetor `palavra`, `b` na posição 1 e `c` na posição 2. O caracter na posição 3 é o terminador de string, o caracter nulo `\0`.

É assim que funciona o `scanf`. Ele preenche o as posições apontadas pelo argumento.

> E outra, por que quando a gente vai ler strings com o `scanf`, mesmo usando o `&`, ele compila?

Porque C tem tipagem fraca. *Muito* fraca.

Por exemplo:

```
char palavra[100];
char *ptr;
char **endereco;

ptr = palavra;
endereco = &ptr;
```

`palavra` é um vetor, uma espécie de "ponteiro constante especial" em C. Já `ptr` é um ponteiro tradicional em C. Então a atribuição `ptr = palavra` está respeitando todas as tipagens.

`endereco`, por sua vez, é outro ponteiro. Um ponteiro para um ponteiro. Por isso faz sentido a atribuição `endereco = &ptr` faz sentido e respeita a tipagem.

Entretanto, a linguagem C não consegue diferenciar em tempo de *runtime* quais os tipos das variáveis. E em nível de compilação C trata ponteiros como ponteiros, independente de qual o tipo apontado. Claro, o compilador vai reclamar, lançar alertas (*warnings* em inglês), mas se você mandou fazer desse jeito, você que sabe.

C não se preocupa se você atirar em seu próprio pé. A linguagem assume que o programador saiba o que está fazendo, então ela não vai lhe oferecer nenhuma segurança contra os seus próprios erros. Se você está fazendo macacada, a da filosofia da linguagem aceitar sua macacada como lei.

Answer (score 7):

A resposta já está na pergunta.

Se está usando um vetor você tem um endereço, e é isto que o `scanf()` espera, um endereço onde ele deve colocar o valor digitado. Uma *string* é um vetor.

Se está usando um tipo primitivo tem o valor e não o endereço, então usa o [operador `&`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101) para pegar o endereço dele e indicar para o `scanf()` onde ele deve colocar o valor.

Quando passa um `&string` está pegando o endereço da variável `txt` que é o mesmo valor que está `txt` está referenciando se for um *array* no *stack*. Se for alocado no *heap* dará problema, como pode ser visto neste código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main(void) {
    char txt[10];
    printf("%p\n", txt); //endereço do array
    printf("%p\n", &txt); //é a mesma coisa, por isso funciona
    scanf("%s", &txt);
    printf("%s\n\n", txt);
    char *txt2 = malloc(10);
    printf("%p\n", txt2); //aqui pega o local de armazenamento
    printf("%p\n", &txt2); //aqui pega o endereço da variável
    scanf("%s", &txt2);
//  printf("%s", txt2);  //quebra
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jWh094). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ayojshcf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/ScanfString.c).

Quando tem ponteiro para o *heap*, a variável, que está no *stack*, guarda o valor dele, o local do armazenamento é que fica no *heap*.

Quando tem um *array* na *stack* já é o local do armazenamento e variável se refere a este local. Quando algo espera um ponteiro e você passa a variável de um *array* já é passado o ponteiro para o local de armazenamento no *stack*. Se usar o `&` ele pega o endereço deste local, que é a mesma coisa.

Não é que funciona por ser tipagem fraca, isto não está afetando nada. Inclusive se fosse por isto provavelmente compilaria, mas não funcionaria. Funciona porque é a mesma coisa.

Claro que a especificação da linguagem não fala nada sobre isto. Não é que seja garantido que seja assim, mas todas implementações que eu conheço tem esse comportamento porque ela faz sentido. O ideal é não fazer já que não está na especificação da linguagem que é permitido, então um dia alguma implementação pode mudar, ainda que improvável.

Talvez a dúvida seria porque não sabe que [o *array* é transformado em ponteiro quando faz algum acesso à sua variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101).

[Dependendo do compilador não compila](https://ideone.com/hwxfSX) já que ele identifica que há algo errado no que está querendo fazer. Mesmo que o acesso seja permitido estritamente falando não deveria usar desta forma. Isto é uma extensão, não é obrigação da linguagem.

Comment: Mas em todos os livros de C, diz que não é necessário colocar o operador de endereço (&) no scanf... Agora me bugou!
E como eu disse na pergunta, o próprio nome do vetor já é o endereço do primeiro elemento. Nesse caso, seria desnecessário usar o & no scanf, já que eu já estaria passando o endereço do vetor. Não entendi....

Comment: E não é necessário mesmo. Mas é possível usar. Só não é considerado o mais adequado. Editei e melhorei a resposta. Talvez te falte entender [o que é uma variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101).

Comment: @PatrickCardoso , é necessário usar para passar o endereço de memória onde será escrito o resultado da leitura. Como um vetor já é um espaço contíguo de memória, você não precisa desse `&` para ler vetores de caracteres

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado isso eu entendi, mas se com vetores de caracteres eu não preciso passar, pq com um vetor de inteiro ou float, eu preciso? Entendeu o que quero dizer? Ainda não consegui compreender totalmente isso.

Comment: @PatrickCardoso você não faz leitura em um único `scanf` de um vetor de inteiros ou de `float`. O que acontece é **uma** leitura de **um elemento**. Para a função `scanf` conseguir escrever esse elemento lido no lugar correto, ele precisa saber chegar nesse lugar. E o ponteiro aponta para um lugar. Entendeu por que para tipos primitivos atômicos se necessita disso?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Agora consegui entender perfeitamente. Muito obrigado!!!!