# print de char retorna caractere aleatorio

Tags: c, linux

Compilo o código abaixo sem erros. Quando insiro a palavra (ou frase desejada) o `printf` me retorna um caractere aleatório como `0` `�` `a` etc. O programa deveria ler uma palavra (ou frase) e o printf mostrar a palavra (ou frase) que foi escrita pelo usuário.

Uso gcc como compilador. Estou compilando pelo terminal no momento. A distro que estou usando é o Manjaro 17.0.5 (não sei se isso interfere em algo).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){

  char example[20];

  scanf("%*c", &example);
  printf("example: %c\n", example);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Porque declarar um vetor e ler apenas um caracter? Também nunca vi esse `*` asterisco no `scanf`, me parece estranho

Comment: Segundo [esse referência](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm), o `*` ignora a leitura do `scanf`. Então, mesmo que você tenha posto endereço de caracter na leitura, o `*` iria fazer a leitura porém não iria armazenar em lugar algum

Comment: Você precisa declarar como String. Um vetor de caracter é uma string.

Comment: Veja mais sobre leitura com `scanf` aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251918/64969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta assim amigo:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char example[20];

    scanf("%[^\n]", &example);
    printf("example: %s", example);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Foi justamente isso que eu estava querendo! Obrigado por compartilhar comigo

Comment: De nada amigo. Boa sorte no seu projeto !

Comment: @RayBM , veja a mensagem do meu comentário de edição.

Comment: @RayBM, você não precisa passar o endereço do vetor para realizar a leitura, fazer `scanf("%[^\n]", example);` já seria o suficiente

Comment: Aqui se deixa explícito o porquê de não precisar do `&` do vetor: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251918/64969

Answer (score 3):

Você está a tentar ler uma palavra/frase:

> O programa deveria ler uma palavra (ou frase) e o printf mostrar a
>   palavra (ou frase)

Mas depois utiliza `%c` que indica caratere (apenas um):

```
scanf("%*c", &example);
printf("example: %c\n", example);
```

Existem várias soluções, e algumas já foram abordadas nas outras respostais tais como `scanf` com `%s`.

Se quiser uma solução robusta utilize [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), que lhe permite especificar o máximo de careteres a ler e tem a garantia que nunca irá ler mais carateres que o limite indicado.

Exemplo com `fgets`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){

  char example[20];

  fgets(example, 20, stdin);
  printf("example: %s\n", example); //%s para string

  return 0;
}
```

[Exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/6YnLU5)

Os 3 parametros do `fgets` são:

1. Local onde é colocado o conteudo lido
2. Tamanho máximo de carateres a ler
3. De onde é feita a leitura, `stdin` indica stream de input que irá corresponder ao teclado

Answer (score 1):

A sua distribuição não interfere, também uso o linux e da o mesmo problema. O seu código não testei num Sistema Operacional Windows, então não sei se lá isso que você desenvolveu vai funcionar. Mas a respeito da String, o seu código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){

  char example[20];

  scanf("%s", &example);
  printf("example: %s\n", example);

  return 0;
}
```

Só tem que tomar cuidado, pois os caracteres em branco são ignorados pelo compilador. Para resolver, teria que usar outra função para capturar a String. Mas acredito que não é seu caso agora.

Comment: O `%s` não leria a frase prevista pela questão. Aproveitando, você não precisa passar o endereço do vetor de caracteres, bastaria usar `scanf("...", example);`, veja mais aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251918/64969