# Programa não cumpre o fluxo esperado lendo e imprimindo entrada

Tags: c, scanf, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{

        int num1, num2, num3;
        printf("Digite o numero A e numero B para saber o resto da divisao resultante da divisao entre eles:\n");
        printf("NumeroA: "); scanf("%i\n", num1);
        printf("\n");
        printf("NumeroB: "); scanf("%i\n", num2);
        printf("O resto da divisao e: %i", num1 % num2);
        return 0;
}
```

Em vez de imprimir o resto, SO imprime o primeiro, o segundo `printf()` e o `scanf()`.

O que estou fazendo de mal?

Também gostaria de saber como posso indicar uma variável num `printf()` (como eu sei Python vou tentar explicar e se alguém souber penso que consegue entender)

```
n = int(input("Digite um numero: "))
m = int(input("Digite outro numero: "))
print (" Imprimiu o numero {} e {}".format(n, m))
```

Sou novo e nisto e tenho apenas 15 anos D, usem linguagem acessível por favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O maior problema é que não está passando o endereço da variável onde deve ser colocado o valor no `scanf()`. Esta função precisa saber onde deve colocar o valor digitado. Passar o valor que está nela não serve para nada. Funciona diferente do Python que o valor é retornado na função.

O [operador `&`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101) pega o endereço da variável. É isto que precisa mudar no código

Na verdade esta função até retorna um valor indicado se der certo ou não a leitura. Em geral em exercícios assim a gente deixa isso pra lá, mas o correto é verificar se a operação foi bem sucedida. Veja a documentação da [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1, num2;
    printf("Digite o numero A e numero B para saber o resto da divisao resultante da divisao entre eles:\n");
    printf("NumeroA: "); scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("\n");
    printf("NumeroB: "); scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("O resto da divisao e: %d", num1 % num2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/p3TxZx). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dnlnvcpi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/Scanf.c).

Já está usando o `printf()` como deve usar. Pode passar uma expressão ou uma variável sem problemas. O que está no `%` é o local que vai cada argumento com a formatação específica. [Veja a formatação](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Melhorei mais algumas coisas, preste atenção ao código.

Recomendo aprender as coisas de forma estruturada e com material bom, especialmente em C. Na tentativa e erro não dá certo.

Comment: Estou aprendendo com YouTube pela playlist Curso de C: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLesCEcYj003SwVdufCQM5FIbrOd0GG1M4 recomenda algo melhor?

Comment: Recomendo livros ou cursos bem conceituados. Estas aulas parecem ruins. Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info.

Answer (score 2):

Faltou o `&` na leitura dos valores no `scanf`. Isto é necessário porque o `scanf` recebe o local na memória onde tem de colocar os valores lidos, que é o que o operador `&` dá.

Faça então assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{

        int num1, num2, num3;
        printf("Digite o numero A e numero B para saber o resto da divisao resultante da divisao entre eles:\n");
        printf("NumeroA: "); scanf("%i", &num1);
        printf("\n");
        printf("NumeroB: "); scanf("%i", &num2);
        printf("O resto da divisao e: %i", num1 % num2);
        return 0;
}
```

Não deve também ter o `\n` no `scanf` caso contrário a leitura dos números não será normal.

A formatação mais normal para números é `%d`, mas `%i` funciona também, podendo reconhecer valores em octal e hexadecimal se prefixados corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que passar o endereço da variável quando usar `scanf()` e você está esperando um `\n` no `scanf()`, no caso não precisa.

Seu código de forma correta ficaria:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{

        int num1, num2, num3;
        printf("Digite o numero A e numero B para saber o resto da divisao resultante da divisao entre eles:\n");
        printf("NumeroA: "); scanf("%i", &num1);
        printf("\n");
        printf("NumeroB: "); scanf("%i", &num2);
        printf("O resto da divisao e: %i", num1 % num2);
        return 0;
}
```