# Código fonte não compila

Tags: c, float, dev-c++

```
#include <iostream>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main() {

    float parede, litros;

    printf ("Calcular litros de tintas  por metros quadrados.\n");
    printf ("Digite a metragem da parede(em metros ao quadrado):");
    scanf("%f", parede);

    if (litros = parede*2/10)
        printf("sao necessarios (litros):");
        scanf("%f", litros);

system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual o significado do operador “&” (e comercial) na linguagem C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125793/qual-o-significado-do-operador-e-comercial-na-linguagem-c)

Comment: Ignorando vários problemas dos quais grande parte já foi assinalado por respostas, porque `<iostream>` se o programa está todo em C ?

Answer (score 1):

No scanf, é necessário o uso do "&":

```
scanf("%f", &parede);
```

O uso do "if" também não é necessário, pois você está atribuindo um valor à variável "litros", e não criando uma condição:

```
litros=(parede*2)/10;
```

Com isso, no resultado final, o printf deverá mostrar:

```
printf("Sao necessarios (litros): %.2f", litros);
```

(O %.2f determinou a quantidade de casas decimais que o programa mostrará, que no caso são 2).

Com isso não há a necessidade do uso do "scanf" após esse printf pois o usuário não irá digitar mais nada, apenas o resultado será impresso.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Existe alguns problemas em seu código, por exemplo
 scanf("%f", parede); é necessario alocar o valor da variavel com &parede)/
outro erro é i IF que não esta correto utiliza-lo já que não há condição no programa( ele vai receber valor, calcular conforme a formula e só), o correto é 
litros = (parede*2)/10; litros irá receber o valor de parede*2 / 10
e para apresentar os valores( printf("sao necessarios (litros)%.2f:\n ", litros);
onde (%.2f): ira chamar a variavel float com 2 digitos após a casa decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar :

```
 if (litros = parede*2)/(10){
    printf("sao necessarios (litros):");
}
    scanf("%f", &litros);
```

Nunca se esqueça de colocar o & quando estiver usando Scanf, caso queira imprimir só dois números dpois da vírgula, use *%.2f* quando for imprimir.
Uma boa dica é abandonar o devC++ (eu acho que você está usando, devido ao *system pause* ali em baixo), eu recomendo usar o **Eclipse** para **C**, e tem a vantagem de rodar no Linux também.