# Diferentes exibições de uma mesma variável em Linguagem C

Tags: c, tipagem

Elaborei o seguinte código e, ao lado de linha os resultados exibidos.
Gostaria de entender o porquê das diferentes exibições.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int inteiro = 1;
float decimal = 6.1;
char caractere1 = 'g';
char caractere2 = "k";

printf("O valor inteiro e %i\n", inteiro); // aparece 1 (está ok)
printf("O valor decimal e %f\n", decimal); // aparece 6.100000 (está ok)
printf("O caractere1 e %c\n", caractere1); // aparece g (está ok)
printf("O caractere2 e %c\n\n", caractere2); // aparece d (está errado - com certeza porque coloquei aspas duplas na declaração da variável)

printf("O valor inteiro e %i\n", &inteiro); // aparece 2293564
printf("O valor decimal e %f\n", &decimal); // aparece 6.099998
printf("O caractere1 e %c\n", &caractere1); // aparece 7
printf("O caractere2 e %c\n", &caractere2); // aparece 6

return 0;
}
```

Comment: da uma olhada aqui http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ ta explicando todas as tags que se pode usar no printf

Comment: %c ler apenas uma letra ou um numero inteiro, quando vc usar aspas duplas no char é como se fosse um "conjunto de letras char[]"

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Não tem muito segredo, é diferente porque o código pediu para ser diferente.

## Representações numéricas para humanos

Uma coisa que eu percebo que as pessoas não entendem que há uma enorme diferença entre o dado e a representação textual para humanos lerem que este dado pode ter.

O dado existe por si só. Não importa como ele está no computador, até porque ele existe como um monte de elétrons e isto não serve para nada no nosso ponto de vista.

Em um nível um pouco mais abstrato representamos como bits, que já é um conceito matemático inventado pelo homem. Um bit pode ser 0 ou 1. Um conjunto de bits formam outros números.

Também podemos dizer que o computador só sabe realizar 3 operações (adição, multiplicação e negação de bits), todas as outras são combinações destas.

Como montamos esses gráficos das aplicações ou jogos? Juntando bits de forma que faça sentido. Tudo o que acontece no computador é assim.

Como fazemos textos aparecerem na tela? Ligamos um monte de pontos na tela que em posições e cores certas desenham o que nós conhecemos como letras, números e outros símbolos. E a forma exata de escrever isso pode variar bastante. Pense em fontes. Então o sistema operacional ou uma aplicação que roda nele pegará um número na memória e verá quais os pontos eles deve ligar para ter o desenho do caractere que é representado por este número.

Tudo isso você não vê, mas está acontecendo no computador. Não tem mágica ou milagre, é só matemática e no nível mais baixo, física.

Mas como sabemos que um número na memória é uma letra? É uma convenção adotada que certos números equivalem a certos caracteres que entendemos. A convenção mais usada é a [tabela ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Mas existem outras e, em tese, você pode criar a sua. Você pode dizer que o número 1 é um desenho de um elefante, que o 25 é nada, que o 345 é um círculo vermelho. Não importa. Claro que tabelas padronizadas fazem mais sentido.

Quando usa um argumento no `printf()` está dizendo como quer que seja apresentado aquele número que está na posição de memória indicada pela variável, expressão ou literal. Poderia ter algum argumento que manda desligar o computador se quisesse, só não faz muito sentido fazer isto.

## Tipagem fraca

Algumas linguagens de programação não deixam um número ser interpretado de forma diferente do que ele foi planejado, isto é característica de [linguagens de tipagem forte. C é uma linguagem de tipagem fraca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101). C faz o que for preciso com qualquer informação que está lá.

Isto é muito flexível e poderoso, porém um pouco perigoso. Tem que saber o que está fazendo e tomar mais cuidado.

## Explicando cada item

```
printf("O valor inteiro e %i\n", &inteiro); // aparece 2293564
```

Está mandando imprimir o [endereço da variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101) `inteiro`, então está certo.

```
printf("O valor decimal e %f\n", &decimal); // aparece 6.099998
```

A mesma coisa, e agora mandando imprimir com as casas decimais. Note que a variável foi declarada como `float`, mas foi usado um literal `double`, parece a mesma coisa, mas nem sempre o resultado será exatamente o mesmo. Isto é [um pouco mais complicado para explicar aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

```
printf("O caractere1 e %c\n", &caractere1); // aparece 7
```

Novamente pegou o endereço. O `%c` trabalha apenas com 1 byte, então  está apenas pegando uma parte do endereço, que já tinha pouco significado, agora tem menos ainda.

```
printf("O caractere2 e %c\n", &caractere2); // aparece 6
```

O mesmo.

```
printf("O caractere2 e %c\n\n", caractere2); // aparece d (está errado - com certeza porque coloquei aspas duplas na declaração da variável)
```

Agora aconteceu o mesmo, mas de forma diferente. Está mandando imprimir um caractere baseado no que receber na variável. O problema já aconteceu na atribuição da variável. Pegou um dado que é do tipo `char *` e tentou guardar em uma variável que é só `char`, então ele pegou o endereço de memória da *string* e guardou em `caractere2` sujando a memória já que a variável tem espaço para apenas 1 byte e o endereço tem 4 ou 8 bytes. Tudo errado.

Entenda que o que está sendo mostrado na tela é sempre uma *string*, que por acaso pode ser composta de caracteres que interpretamos como dígitos numéricos.

## Outras questões

Não gosto muito do nome da variável `decimal` (nem estou falando do fato que o nome não descreve o dado e sim o tipo, afinal isso é só uma demonstração) porque ele não é bem um decimal. Até é, mas de computador que [é bem diferente do decimal que nós conhecemos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). Por isso chama `float` e `double` e não `decimal`.

Tive que usar um compilador configurado para aceitar certas construções erradas, caso contrário nem compilava isso.

Perceba que aparecem coisas diferentes, afinal a memória está diferente.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int inteiro = 1;
    float decimal = 6.1f;
    char caractere1 = 'g';
    char *caractere2 = "k";
    printf("O valor inteiro e %i\n", inteiro); // aparece 1 (está ok)
    printf("O valor decimal e %f\n", decimal); // aparece 6.100000 (está ok)
    printf("O caractere1 e %c\n", caractere1); // aparece g (está ok)
    printf("O caractere2 e %c\n\n", caractere2); // aparece d (está errado - com certeza porque coloquei aspas duplas na declaração da variável)
    printf("O valor inteiro e %i\n", &inteiro); // aparece 2293564
    printf("O valor decimal e %f\n", &decimal); // aparece 6.099998
    printf("O caractere1 e %c\n", &caractere1); // aparece 7
    printf("O caractere2 e %c\n\n", &caractere2); // aparece 6
    
    printf("O caractere2 e %s\n", caractere2);
    printf("O valor inteiro (somado para dar algo imprimível) mostrado como caractere e %c\n", inteiro + 64);
    printf("O endereco de decimal e %d\n", &decimal);
    printf("O inicio do caractere2 e %c\n", caractere2[0]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CTeTWV). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zultkrbz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/TextRepresentation.c).

Tem situação que a formação da memória causa um problema por causa da sujeira na memória. Se executar algumas linhas e outras não funciona, funciona mesmo que as que geram problema sejam executadas sem algumas outras. A composição delas cria problema.

Por isso que eu sempre falo que funcionar e estar certo são coisas diferentes, o mesmo código gera resultados diferentes em máquinas diferentes porque não está certo.

[image: Funciona e estar certo são coisas distintas]

Comment: "Tive que usar um compilador configurado para aceitar certas construções erradas, caso contrário nem compilava isso." Estou usando o CodeBlocks... qual seria o compilador ideal para quem está iniciando?

Comment: CodeBlocks não é um compilador. Se estiver usando WIndows eu instalaria o Visual Studio e usaria o compilador da Microsoft mesmo. Se for Linux use o GCC, mas versões mais novas sempre. Eu tenho pendido para o Clang também.

Answer (score 1):

**Para melhor entender**

Você lembra do scanf("%d",&inteiro); ?

scanf(); é comando de leitura;

%d (ou %i) é para representar decimais inteiros;

& é para representar o endereço;

Logo  scanf("%d",&inteiro);  você vai por conteúdo inteiro em determinada posição da memória.

***Esse você está pegando o conteúdo dentro da posição de memória:***

```
 printf("O valor inteiro e %i\n", inteiro); // aparece 1 (está ok)
 printf("O valor decimal e %f\n", decimal); // aparece 6.100000 (está ok)
 printf("O caractere1 e %c\n", caractere1); // aparece g (está ok)
 printf("O caractere2 e %c\n\n", caractere2); // aparece d (está errado - 
com certeza porque coloquei aspas duplas na declaração da variável)
```

***Esse você está pegando o endereço da memória:***

```
printf("O valor inteiro e %i\n", &inteiro); // aparece 2293564
printf("O valor decimal e %f\n", &decimal); // aparece 6.099998
printf("O caractere1 e %c\n", &caractere1); // aparece 7
printf("O caractere2 e %c\n", &caractere2); // aparece 6
```