# Retorno de refência em C++

Tags: c++, ponteiro, referência

Não consigo entender o que a função a seguir retorna.

```
int * begin(){ //
  return &this->data[0];
}
```

Essa tal função retorna o endereço de uma referência? Não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Dê mais contexto ao código. Qual é o tipo de `this->data`?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 4):

Ela retorna um ponteiro, que é um endereço de algum objeto. O [**operador** `&`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101) pega um endereço do objeto em vez de pegar o objeto em si.

No caso retorna o endereço de `this`, que tem grande chance de ser um ponteiro ou referência. Aí fico pensando se a intenção não era retornar o próprio `this`.

Deve estar havendo uma confusão porque a declaração `&` indica que algo é uma referência, mas dependendo do contexto o mesmo símbolo é o operador é outra coisa bem diferente, apesar de ter uma relação.

Entenda [Qual a diferença entre ponteiro e referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101).

Answer (score 2):

Talvez existam outras possibilidades. Mas uma delas é um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento do array `data` do objeto de uma classe que implementa a função membro `begin()`.

- `this` se refere ao ponteiro para o objeto cuja função esta sendo chamada.
- os operadores `->` e `[]` precedem o operador `&`, então vamos a eles.

  - A associatividade desses dois operadores é da esquerda para a direita.
  - Nesse caso `this->data` é um ponteiro para o array `data`.
  - E `this->data[0]` é um inteiro. O primeiro elemento do array `data`.
- finalmente o operador `&` retorna o endereço do inteiro `this->data[0]`.

Observe que nesse caso, `this->data` e `&this->data[0]` retornam o mesmo valor.

Uma possível implementação:

```
#include <iostream>

struct s {
  s() : data{1, 2, 3} {};
  int *begin() { return &this->data[0]; };
  int data[3];
};

int main() {
  s var;
  std::cout << *var.begin() << "\n";
}
```