# Qual é a diferença das expressões : "int a" e "const int& a" como argumentos de funções em C++?

Tags: c++, parâmetros, referência, const

Vamos supor que eu tenho duas funções:

```
int soma_a(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

e

```
int soma_b(const int& a, const int& b){
    return a + b;
}
```

Qual seria a diferença entre `soma_a()` e `soma_b()`

Comment: [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705593/int-vs-const-int) similar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O primeiro está sendo passado por valor, ou seja, o valor do argumento que está sendo usado na chamada desta função é copiado para o parâmetro da função `soma_a()`.

O segundo o valor do argumento não é copiado, uma referência é usada no lugar, ou seja, opacamente um ponteiro é criado apontando o local onde está o valor do argumento e esse endereço é copiado para o parâmetro da função `soma_b()`. Como há um `const` significa que a função está proibida de mudar esse valor, ele será só leitura, portanto há um contrato garantindo para o chamador que o valor ficará intacto.

Em um `int` não faz sentido porque o `int` costuma ter o mesmo tamanho ou até é menor que o tamanho de um ponteiro, então a cópia custa a mesma coisa ou mais cara. geralmente isto é mais útil em casos que a estrutura passada é maior que um ponteiro.

Na forma escrita ambos se comportarão exatamente igual, mas o primeiro será mais eficiente neste caso específico.

Se não tivesse o `const` aí ele poderia ser útil para fazer com que o parâmetro servisse como saída também, então a mudança do valor dele dentro da função causaria um efeito colateral no argumento, afinal o argumento e o parâmetro estão no mesmo endereço, você passou o endereço, não um valor de forma independente, eles estão completamente ligados porque é a mesma coisa. Neste caso o argumento tem que ser uma variável.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int soma_b(int& a, const int& b) {
    a = 4;
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    int x = 2;
    cout << soma_b(x, 3) << endl;
    cout << x;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CW8mj4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zekjgxzh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Pointer/ReferenceVar.cpp).

leituras importantes para entender melhor o assunto e algumas relacionadas, mesmo que em outra linguagem:

- [Qual a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101)
- [Como é a referência do C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81611/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre ponteiro e referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101)
- [Por que em métodos set no C++ eu tenho que usar o parâmetro como referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149513/101)
- [Retorno de refência em C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/289815/101)
- [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101)

Comment: Muda alguma coisa na performance?

Comment: Além do que eu falei, não.

Comment: "Como há um const significa que a função está proibida de mudar esse valor" — exceto se você usar `const_cast` e o objeto original não tiver o qualificador `const`, nesse caso você pode modificar o referenciado.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi sim, é possível contornar, mas você explicitamente está dizendo um f0d@-se pro contrato estabelecido

Answer (score 0):

Em C++ , além de variáveis, nós podemos usar também números ou caracteres cujos valores não mudam. Eles são chamados de constantes. Nesse caso, na `soma_b`, você faz referencia ás variáveis `a` e `b` como sendo constantes, sendo assim, os valores delas nao podem ser alterados. (nem mesmo com um comando `cin >> a >> b >> endl;`