# Diferença entre usar "std::string" ou "std::string&" como parâmetro de função

Tags: c++, string, funções, parâmetros

Tenho uma função que adiciona cor a uma `string`:

```
inline std::string red(std::string stream)       
{
    return "\033[0;31m" + stream + "\033[0m";
}
```

Ela funciona normalmente com variáveis do tipo `std::string`:

```
std::string str = "hello, world";

std::cout << red(str) << std::endl;
```

Mas ocorre um erro ao usar uma string literal (`const char*`):

```
std::cout << red("hello, world") << std::endl;
```

Porém percebi que ao adicionar `&`, o erro não ocorria mais:

```
inline std::string red(std::string& stream)       
{
    return "\033[0;31m" + stream + "\033[0m";
}
```

Até onde eu sei o operador `&` no contexto de argumentos serve para passar um argumento por referência, então por que colocando esse operador a função parou de dar erro?

Comment: poste algo compilável, completo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Tenho uma função que adiciona cor a uma string*

Não, está apenas adicionando um outro texto a um já existente, não tem nada de cor aí. O texto que está adicionando poderá ser usado de forma especial em certos cenários, por exemplo em algum tipo de console, não em todos, não em outros dispositivos ou outros contextos da programação. Interpretar como cor é algo que outro mecanismo faz.

> *até onde eu sei o operador `&` no contexto de argumentos*

Na verdade este indicador de declaração de tipo só pode ser feito em [parâmetros, não em argumentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101). Isto não é um [operador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101), tem um [operador idêntico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101), mas ele só é usado em outro contexto.

Isto indica que o parâmetro será recebido por referência, se não for assim será uma cópia.

Eu não consegui reproduzir o problema indicado, na verdade o que diz ter sido a solução deu erro para mim. Talvez esteja usando um compilador ultrapassado ou problemático, ou alguma configuração de compilação inadequada, se for o caso aconselho mudar.

Para funcionar por referência deve garantir a constância do valor no parâmetro, sem isso a função poderia tentar modificar o valor que está em área estática da memória, um local que não pode ser alterado. O primeiro está na pilha e pode ser alterado, embora provavelmente não seja o que deseja. Por valor haveria uma cópia (na verdade *copy on write*, então não precisaria copiar de verdade) e por isso não tem perigo. Você pode ver a [documentação do tipo](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) para mais detalhes.

Não foi o postado o erro, mas não vou falar dele porque já é de conhecimento.

Maneira correta, simplificando o código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string red(string stream) {
    return "\033[0;31m" + stream + "\033[0m";
}

string red2(const string& stream) {
    return "\033[0;31m" + stream + "\033[0m";
}

int main() {
    auto str = "hello, world";
    cout << red(str) << endl;
    cout << red("hello, world") << endl;
    cout << red2(str) << endl;
    cout << red2("hello, world") << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iJrcwU). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/iuplszqlif-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Function/StringParameter.cpp).

De forma geral a segunda função não é necessária, só postei para mostrar a forma correta se quiser usar a referência.

[Veja explicação mais detalhada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/320739/101).

Answer (score 4):

Você tem uma função que retorna uma string a partir de outra, colocando um prefixo e um sufixo. Daí a eventualmente escrever em vermelho é um outro caminho e nada tem a ver com seu problema.

`std::string red(std::string stream)` espera uma string como parâmetro. E nesse caso:

```
std::string str = "hello, world";
std::cout << red(str) << std::endl;
```

é uma string mesmo e o construtor de cópia da classe string será chamado para criar a string a ser usada em `red()`.

No caso de `red("hello, world")` a função recebe `const char[13]`, mas o construtor da classe `string` tem um *overload* que aceita `const char*` e assim em `red()` `stream` é criada sem problemas. Não é o construtor de cópia mas sim esse *overload* que é usado.

Mas se você declara

```
inline std::string red(std::string& stream)
```

então `red()` espera uma referência para uma string. Claro que ao chamar com
`red("hello, world")` a função continua recebendo `const char[13]`, e o compilador vai rapidamente te dizer que não há como transformar uma coisa na outra, com algo como

```
 'std::string red(std::string &)': \
  cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [13]' to 'std::string &'
```

### Sobre o erro

> até onde eu sei o operador '&' no contexto de argumentos serve para
> passar um argumento por referência, então alguem poderia me explicar o
> porque colocando esse operador a função parou de dar erro

Ao contrário, passando a string para `red()` por referência é que vai dar erro ao chamar com uma contante.

### Sobre as cores e `red()`

A bit off-topic mas provavelmente sua função estaria melhor com um nome tipo `console_print` e recebendo a cor como parâmetro. Desde '18 tem uma convergência do Windows para o Linux em torno de aceitar sequências como a que descreveu. A Microsoft chama isso de *Terminal Virtual*.Essas sequências vem desde os terminais VT-52 e VT-100 da Digital no Unix nos '80 e devem funcionar OK no Terminal do Windows e no xterm e derivados no Linux e no Mac. Note que existem `constantes` definidas para as cores, tanto no Windows quanto no Linux/Mac/Android, nos headers apropriados.