# Erro na coversão de 'int' para 'int*'

Tags: c++, ponteiro, parâmetros, int

Queria saber por que está causando o erro:

> Erro na conversão de 'int' para 'int*'

Este programa é apenas para treinar o uso de ponteiros em parâmetros.

```
void teste(int *t){

*t = 50;
}   

int main(){

int x = 10;

cout << "Sem usar o metodo com ponteiro: " << x << endl;

teste(x);

cout << "Usando o metodo com ponteiro: " << x << endl;  

return 0;   
}
```

Comment: O que você entendeu da definição de ponteiros?

Comment: Bom o ponteiro é uma variavel que armazena o endereço de outra, posso manipular qual quer variavel em qual quer parte do meu codigo, essa é a ideia que aprendi sobre ponteiros

Comment: Mas você precisa declarar esse ponteiro no seu código e definir qual variável ele irá manipular.

Comment: Ah então só pode usar uma um parametro de ponteiro, sendo um ponteiro? eu passo o endereço da viriavel X para um ponteiro, e uso o ponteiro na função?

Comment: @RenanUstolin A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Só faltou dizer que você quer passar o endereço e não o valor, afinal a função está esperando um endereço de um valor e não o valor em si. Usa-se o [`&`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101).

```
void teste(int *t) {
    *t = 50;
}   

int main() {
    int x = 10;
    cout << "Sem usar o metodo com ponteiro: " << x << endl;
    teste(&x);
    cout << "Usando o metodo com ponteiro: " << x << endl;   
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Uf2Rsp). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/feddtvwg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Pointer/Parameter.cpp).

Comment: Olha se não é pedir muito, você poderia me dizer alguma situação que é util o uso de ponteiros como parametros?

Comment: Ponteiro puro em C++ se não for exigido pela função que está usando quase nunca, é melhor usar referência ou um ponteiro inteligente. Mas se usar é porque não quer transferir o valor e sim onde está o valor. Quando precisa que uma alteração feita na função chamada reflita na variável da função chamadora. Você cria uma indireção. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101