# Decremento, incremento e soma de ponteiros em C

Tags: c, ponteiro

Por que quando tento somar o ultimo ponteiro em mais 15 ele repete o antepenúltimo ponteiro e não soma o o ponteiro `*ptr_xi` com mais 15?

```
int xi;

int *ptr_xi;

void imprimir() 

    printf("valor de xi = %d \n", xi);
    printf("valor de &xi = %p \n", &xi);
    printf("valor de ptr_xi = %p \n", ptr_xi);
    printf("valor de *ptr_xi = %d \n\n", *ptr_xi);
}

main() 
{

    xi = 10;
    ptr_xi = &xi;
    imprimir();

    xi = 20;
    imprimir();

    *ptr_xi = 30;
    imprimir();

    (*ptr_xi)--;
    imprimir();

    (*ptr_xi)++;
    imprimir();

    (*ptr_xi)++;
    imprimir();

    *(ptr_xi+15);
    imprimir();

    system ("Pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Em todos os anteriores você não está somando ponteiros, está somando valores apontados por variáveis ponteiros. Isto é muito diferente, faz o que provavelmente queria, mudar os valores associados. Nada disso é necessário ponteiro, pode servir para visualizar o que acontece, mas cuidado para não acharque é assim que se usa ponteiro.

No último é o único que está somando ponteiro. Manipula o ponteiro em si. Ele está indo 15 posições de memória à frente da posição original onde estava o valor que quer manipular. Como é um `int` provavelmente (não é certo, depende da plataforma) ele tem 4 bytes, então 15 posições são 60 bytes à frente. O que tem 60 posições à frente? Nesse caso é lixo, algo que você não tem controle, então vai acessar uma área com informação que podemos dizer quase aleatória, ou até onde não pode.

Sempre que tem um ponteiro o valor da variável é um endereço de memória, note que você usou um [operador `&`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101) para pegar o endereço de memória onde tinha um valor. Quando tem um ponteiro tem duas informações o endereço apontador e o valor que é apontado. Quando você manipula a variável do ponteiro está manipulando o endereço da memória. Quando quer manipular o valor, tem que pegar o endereço, fazer a indireção para o local apontado e lá é que manipula o valor, por isso usou parênteses, para pegar primeiro o local e depois fazer a operação. No último manipulou o local e depois pegou o valor nesse novo local.

Answer (score 1):

Isso aconteceu porque nos outros casos do seu código você está atribuindo um valor para a variável `xi`, seja na própria variável, seja através de ponteiro, enquanto que no caso dessa sua dúvida você não está atribuindo nada, nem à variável e nem ao ponteiro, ou seja, é como se você estivesse deixando nessa linha da sua dúvida uma soma "solta", sem nenhum efeito para o cálculo, é como se você escrevesse na linha dessa sua dúvida assim `(xi + 15);`. A compilação se daria normalmente, dependendo do editor, mas visto que essa soma não foi guardada em variável alguma, essa soma se perderá no código.
O correto, portanto, seria, na linha da sua dúvida, guardar essa soma, escrevendo assim:
`*ptr_xi = *ptr_xi + 15;` ou `*ptr_xi += 15;`.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).