# Como usar ("%10.2f",&d) em C quero que o numero sai inteiro

Tags: c, c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() 
{
        int a,b,c,d;
        printf("Escolha Qual das equacoes se adequa a sua duvida de 1 a 3\n\n");
        printf("?+X=X     escolha (1) \nX+?=X     escolha (2)\nX+X=?     escolha (3)    \n");
        scanf("%i",&a);
        switch(a) {
            case 1:  printf("Apenas Digite os numeros que faltam sem os sinais no modelo ?+X=X \n ");
                     scanf("%i",&b);
                     scanf("%i",&c);
                     d=b-c;
                     printf("%10.2f",&d);

            break;


        }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente está a imprimir o endereço de memoria da variável quando utiliza o operador `&`:

```
printf("%10.2f", &d);
//               ^---
```

Depois o formatador `f`, serve para valores de virgula flutuante, assim como a [documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) indica:

> Decimal floating point, lowercase

No entanto se imprime um `int` onde a função espera um `float` não irá apresentar o número de forma correta pois um `float` não é armazenado da mesma maneira que um `int` em relação aos bits.

Se quiser ainda assim imprimir o inteiro como se fosse um `float` pode fazer uma conversão para `float` no momento da impressão que já lhe dá o resultado que estaria à espera:

```
printf("%10.2f", (float)d);
```

Ainda assim, se fez operações tudo em inteiros o resultado será sempre um inteiro, e por isso a parte decimal será sempre `.00`

Leitura recomendada:

[Qual o significado do operador “&” (e comercial) na linguagem C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125793/qual-o-significado-do-operador-e-comercial-na-linguagem-c)

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de utilizar assim,   `printf("%10.2f",&d);`coloca da seguinte maneira`printf("%i",d);`

pois voce ja definiu acima que "d" é inteiro.