# Meu programa compila mas trava no primeiro printf

Tags: c, codeblocks

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int n1,n2,n3,maior,menor;
    printf("Primeiro numero: ");
    scanf("%d", n1);
    printf("Segundo numero: ");
    scanf("%d", n2);
    printf("Terceiro numero: ");
    scanf("%d", n3);
    if (n1>n2&&n1>n3)
    {
        maior=n1;
        if (n2>n3)
            menor=n3;
        else
            menor=n2;
    }
    else if (n2>n1&&n2>n3)
    {
        maior=n2;
        if (n1>n3)
            menor=n3;
        else
            menor=n1;
    }
    else
    {
        maior=n3;
        if (n1>n2)
            menor=n2;
        else
            menor=n1;
    }
    printf("Menor numero: %d\nMaior numero: %d",menor,maior);
}
```

Após perguntar o primeiro numero e eu dar a resposta, o programa trava. Alguém sabe o por que disso? Estou usando CodeBlocks pois é recomendado  pela universidade.

Comment: Oi. Qual a entrada que está colocando no sistema?

Comment: @alwaysNever Você esqueceu do operador E comercial (&) antes dos nomes da variáveis em cada scanf. Leitura recomendada -> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125793/qual-o-significado-do-operador-e-comercial-na-linguagem-c

Comment: MEU DEUS era isso, obg. Se eu soubesse dar pontinho eu dava. Estou compilando em C pro outro comentário

Answer (score 3):

Faltou colocar & antes da variável no scanf. Por isso é muito melhor usar a biblioteca  e usar cin ao inves de scanf.
Voce usou "return 0" no final?

Seu codigo ficaria (trecho):

## include

using namespace std;
void main()
{
    int n1,n2,n3,maior,menor;

```
cout <<"Primeiro numero: ";
cin >> n1;
cout <<"Segundo numero: ";
cin >> n;
cout <<"Terceiro numero: ";
cin >> n3;
if (n1>n2&&n1>n3)
{
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá!

Você deve utilizar o & nas variáveis quando utilizar o scanf.
Exemplo: scanf("%d", &n1);
Pois o valor que você digitar será armazenado no endereço de n1, quando você estiver no tópico de ponteiros compreenderá melhor. Caso continue com dúvidas, visite o site http://linguagemc.com.br

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, O Code::Blocks é uma bela de uma *****!
Sem brincadeiras.

Segundo, inclua o `<stdlib.h>`

Terceiro, dê um valor de 0 a todas as variáveis (sempre atribua um valor a cada variável que você declara!).

Espero que resolva teu problema! :D

Comment: CodeBlocks é o único IDE q tem instalado no PC da universidade infelizmente :V
Eu inclui o <stdlib.h> e coloquei valor 0 em td, ainda trava :( mas obrigado pela ajuda