# Por que uma variável passada para função não mantém o valor alterado quando sai da função?

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, tipagem, parâmetros

Estou querendo querendo que as variáveis latitude e longitude sejam atualizadas, mas apenas as variáveis `lon` e `lat` estão sendo alteradas. Não posso adicionar `latitude = latitude - 1` ou `longitude= longitude + 1`.

[image: Print do meu terminal no Code Blocks]

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Você está passando variáveis por referência quando usa o `&`, então não está passando um valor, está passando o **endereço** onde tem um valor. Pode ler mais sobre isso em [Qual o significado do operador "&" (e comercial) na linguagem C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101).

Na definição da função está recebendo valores normais com o tipo `int`. Quando chama a função passa um endereço, o valor que sua função está recebendo é o endereço de uma variável, então quando manipula o valor está mudando o endereço ali estabelecido e mais nada, o que terá uma ação inócua.

Se você precisa passar um endereço deve receber um endereço. E para dizer isso tem que usar o tipo `int *` (ou outro tipo de aponte para um valor de outro tipo), não pode ser só o tipo básico, tem que ser um ponteiro para o tipo.

Não basta mudar no parâmetro, tem que fazer isso em todo acesso à variável porque você quer acesso o valor e não o endereço. Lembre-se que esse variável é sempre o endereço e não é o que deseja manipular, por exemplo `*lat`. Feito isso você muda o valor que deseja.

Eu mostraria com um exemplo, mas como o AP não facilitou pra gente e eu teria que digitar todo o código para isso, ficará só a explicação. As respostas não podem ser tão boas quando as perguntas não foram feitas de forma melhor.

Comment: Acho que entendi, no parâmetro da função eu passei apenas o endereço da variável, então a função void vai receber esse endereço, portanto isso só irá mudar o valor do endereço. Mas, porque a saída deu logo o valor de latitude e longitude sem alteração?

Comment: Está na resposta, você alterou o endereço e isso é inócuo nesse código.

Comment: mas, porque inócuo? Não era para aparecer um valor equivalente a posição da variável descrementada?

Comment: Está na resposta, você está mexendo no endereço e não no valor, então o valor não está sendo alterado.

Comment: Altere os parâmetros de sua função para `(int * lat, int * lon)` e as operações para `*lat -= 1;` e `*lon += 1;` e avalie os resultados. Depois estude a diferença da passagem de parâmetros quando você passa um valor e quando você passa um endereço.