# Sub-rotina em C não executa

Tags: c

O objetivo do programa que estou criando é receber a distancia que 15 carros(simulei com 3 para acelerar o processo de teste) percorreram durante o dia.
A distância pode ser informada em quilômetros, metros ou milhas.
O programa tem que retornar a distância total em quilômetros.

Esse é o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

float testeMedida(char medida,float total) {
    if (strcmp(medida,"km") == 0) {
        return total;
    } else if (strcmp(medida,"mt") == 0) {
        return total/1000;
    } else if (strcmp(medida,"mi") == 0) {
        return total*1.60934;
    }
}

void main() {
    float distancia[3];
    float resultado, totalConveter;
    int i;
    char medida[5];

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("Digite a distancia percorrida pelo carro %d: ",i);
        scanf("%f",&distancia[i]);

        totalConveter = totalConveter + distancia[i];
    }

    printf("\nQual a unidade utilizada?\n");
    printf("km = quilometros\n");
    printf("mt = metros\n");
    printf("mi = milhas\n");
    printf("Unidade utilizada: ");
    scanf("%s",&medida);

    resultado = testeMedida(medida,totalConveter);

    printf("\nA distancia total percorrida pelos carros são de %.2f quilometros.",resultado);

    getchar();
}
```

Porém ao executar o código, o programa não retorna a distancia total do último `printf`. Ele se encerra após informar a unidade de medida.

O que pode ser?

Desde já, obrigado pela atenção. :)

Comment: Você está passando uma _string_ (um vetor/sequência de caracteres, ou seja, tipo `char[]`) para um parâmetro que você definiu que deveria ser um único caractere, ou seja, tipo `char`.

Comment: Muito obrigado Gustavo Sampaio. Estava quebrando a cabeça e até agora não tinha notado isso. Estou iniciando na área da programação.

Comment: Problema resolvido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rodei seu programa no Codeblocks e ele me apontou uma série de warnings que precisaram ser tratados. Vamos enumerando 1 a 1 para que você possa corrigir seu código e executar seu programa:

1. **|6|warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|** ----> O aviso aqui é para lhe informar que na linha 6 do seu código, a funcao strcmp está recebendo um parametro que não é um ponteiro de char, portanto essa funcao nao executara corretamente.Seu problema pode ser resolvido modificando a funcao testeMedida() para receber um ponteiro de char, ficando da seguinte forma:

   ```
   float testeMedida(char medida[5],float total) { /* corrigido tambem o parametro de entrada
    char medida que precisava do complemento com o tamanho da char. */ 
    if (strcmp(medida,"km") == 0) {
        return total;
    } else if (strcmp(medida,"mt") == 0) {
        return total/1000;
    } else if (strcmp(medida,"mi") == 0) {
        return total*1.60934;
    } else { 
    return -1;
    } 
   } /* Note que acrescentei um else a mais para que a função retorne -1
      caso nenhuma das hipóteses de cima sejam atendidas. Se não acrescentasse, não haveria
      retorno em algum momento e o código apresentaria erro.
   ```

2 **warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]**: Seguindo as boas práticas em C e salientando que em C++ void main() é proibido, por gentileza troca void main() por int main(), assim o programa retornará o valor 0 pra voce caso tudo tenha ocorrido bem, e -1 caso haja algum erro.

3  **warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]**: É um aviso do compilador que informa a necessidade de por um retorno padrão para a função testeMedida(). Este aviso some quando você poem o else a mais igual eu fiz ali em cima.

4 **|33|warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[5]’ [-Wformat=]|**: Neste aviso, é possível perceber que na linha 33 o scanf espera receber o tipo char *(ponteiro de char) qualquer, porem você informou &medida, e no caso de um conjunto de char, nao é possivel nesse caso realizar uma passagem de parametro por referencia. Voce deve tirar o & sem medo de ser feliz que o scanf continuará jogando o texto digitado na variavel e irá parar de apresentar mensagem de warning.

Mais sobre o & e ponteiros em: [Qual o significado do operador "&" (e comercial) na linguagem C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125793/qual-o-significado-do-operador-e-comercial-na-linguagem-c)

Executes estes rebocos e sua obra estará pronta.

Comment: Obrigado Alexandre Guerreiro.